# "Ни... ни" с глаголами

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно так сказать или нет:

*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время ни размагнитилась, ни как-то иначе испортилась*?

Не могу поверить, чтобы правильно было заменить оба *"ни"* не *"ни не"*. Конечно, многие могут сказать, что можно перефразировать: *Я надеюсь, что с карточкой за это время ничего не произошло: ни...* Но действительно ли это единственный вариант? Нельзя сказать, как у меня, или близко к этому? Вариант с "не... и не" не рассматриваю как слабый, хочется именно с "ни" сказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время ни размагнитилась, ни как-то иначе испортилась.**

В данном случае вместо отрицательных частиц НЕ используется союз НИ... НИ, который обозначает и отрицание, и усиление отрицания.

Сравнить: Я здесь останусь смело. Вот ваши сестры - как хотят; А ведь Ворон **ни жарят, ни варят** (И. Крылов).

Союз НИ... НИ не просто отрицает два действия, но и обобщает: ничего с ними не делают.

Comment: Спасибо, Арина! Значит, Вы уверены, что так правильно и в моём, более распространённом случае? (Надеюсь, я правильно это назвал? Имею в виду зависимые слова.)  А почему "Вороны" с большой буквы, не знаете?

Comment: Думаю, что значение отрицание + усиление  в вашем "распространенном" варианте то же самое.  Вы же имели в виду - ничего с ними не случится.  А Ворона из басни, там все персонажи пишутся с прописной буквы, как имена собственные.

Comment: Вороны во множественном числе, так что это не конкретный персонаж.) Ну да ладно, не важно. А тому, что достаточно просто НИ... НИ, я только очень рад!)) Просто не было уверенности, что так сказать грамотно.

Answer (score 1):

> *Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время ни размагнитилась, ни как-то иначе испортилась.*

Как звучит? По-моему, ужасно!

> В современном русском языке частица ***ни*** используется для усиления
>   отрицания, которое есть в предложении и которое выражается частицей
>   ***не*** или словами ***нет, нельзя***. Усиление отрицания (быть спутником слов ***не, нет, нельзя***) –  основная функция частицы
>   ***ни***: Он никогда **не** был **ни** прекрасным, **ни** хорошим, а был самым обыкновенным учеником.
>
> (Кайдалова А. И., Калинина И. К. "Современная русская орфография", М.,
>   1983)

Может эта частица в значении *"и не"* использоваться и в предложениях, где нет слов *не, нет, нельзя*. Но – не при сказуемых! На примеры из ХIХ века ссылаться некорректно. Вот как выглядит современное написание, к примеру, предложения из басни Крылова, приведённое Ариной в своём ответе в этой теме:

> § 1525. *…А ведь ворон **не** жарят, **не** варят.*
>
> ([**Грамматика–80**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1516-1548.html))

А разбираемое предложение стоит переработать.

Как вариант:

*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время **не** успела **ни** размагнититься, **ни** как-то иначе испортиться.*

Comment: slava, а что вы думаете по поводу разбора этой темы у Розенталя?
 http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82#pp82   3. Повторяющаяся частица ни имеет значение соединительного союза: Ни день, ни месяц от него не было вестей; По этой дороге ни проехать, ни пройти; Ни тихо, ни громко течёт рассказ. В этих случаях ни по значению равно сочетанию и не, т. е. выступает в функции отрицания. Ср. у писателей XIX в.: Ворон ни жарят, ни варят (Кр.); Сам он ни богат, ни знатен, ни умён (Т.); Елисей был старичок ни богатый, ни бедный (Л. Т.). И далее - примечание.

Comment: Кроме того, я думаю что во всех фразеологических сочетаниях используется именно это значение союза НИ...НИ: ни много ни мало, ни рыба ни мясо и т.д. Кстати, " ворон ни варят, ни жарят" печатают и в современных текстах http://narodstory.net/basni_krilov.php?id=15

Comment: Спасибо за мнение, Слава! Жду, что ответите Арине.

Comment: Непонятно, как к однородным сказуемым могут относиться разные частицы НЕ и НИ (не размагнитилась, ни как-то иначе не испортилась). Думаю, что возможен еще один вариант записи: Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время и не размагнитилась, и не испортилась как-то иначе. То есть по Розенталю мы делаем замену НИ=И+НЕ.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, Арина! И Ваш предыдущий вариант мне больше нравился, Слава! Этот действительно совсем странный.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: "И Ваш предыдущий вариант мне больше нравился, Слава!"_ === ОК! Восстановил его в своём ответе.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: "Заменил кавычки, надеюсь, Вы не против. В русском вроде одиночные не приняты"._  === Да??? А у Кайдаловой с Калининой, чей учебник я цитировал, стоят одиночные. Правда, тогда ещё нашего сайта не существовало, и некому им было сделать такого замечания...

Comment: И по поводу пробелов между инициалами… Артём Луговой, ну с чего Вы решили, что они обязательны? Я эти пробелы не ставлю сознательно, считаю их излишними.  Знаком с рекомендациями справочного бюро Грамоты.ру об их использовании, но… В ПРАВИЛАХ что-либо по поводу необходимости пробелов между инициалами есть? НЕТ! А потому, пожалуйста, не портите в будущем мои ответы **лишними** исправлениями.

Comment: @slava1947: простите, Слава, давайте не будем ругаться. Спасибо, что сказали! Давно пора было. А то, что у этих авторов одиночные кавычки стоят, это какое-то недоразумение. Непонятно, почему им такое в голову пришло. Может, просто случайно не те выбрали. А может, из-за чего-то нельзя было поставить обычные. Кстати, Вы Арине так и не ответили.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Кстати, Вы Арине так и не ответили._ === Просто хочу посмотреть, как много её (на мой взгляд, абсолютно нечитаемый) вариант (_**"Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время ни размагнитилась, ни как-то иначе испортилась."_**) с "ни как-то иначе" перед сказуемым наберёт плюсов на этом сайте. (Жаль только, имен этих голосующих не видно...)

Comment: Честно сказать, один из них я. :) А кто второй, тоже не представляю, конечно. Если считаете это справедливым, могу убрать свой голос, вот только минусовать ей рейтинг теперь как-то не очень хорошо...

Answer (score 0):

*Не размагнититься* значит сохраниться в рабочем состоянии. «Слабость» этого варианта можно было бы компенсировать, заменив ***надеюсь*** на ***почти уверен***.

*Размагнититься* — глагол со значением — аннулировать результат предшествующего действия, то есть глагол с заложенным отрицанием (ср.: гримироваться — разгримироваться; любить — разлюбить; морозить — разморозить). Таким образом, *не не размагнититься* (за счёт приставки *раз-*) становиться уже трижды отрицающей действия конструкцией, которую можно причислить к саморазрушающимся — невозможным.

Остаётся вариант со связкой *Ни... ни*, где отрицание есть, но не столь нарочитое.

Чтобы фраза не теряла темпа, сдвинул бы *как-то иначе* в её конец: «*Почти уверен, что карточка за это время ни размагнитилась, ни испортилась как-то иначе.»*

Comment: Спасибо! Насчёт тройного отрицания интересно подметили!) А вот замена на "почти уверен" меняет всё-таки смысл. "Надеюсь" выражает неспособность рассчитать, могло что-то произойти или нет, то есть отсутствие научных знаний, чтобы это оценить, или хотя бы достаточного жизненного опыта. А "почти уверен" должно скорее всего предполагать какие-то знания или доводы, на которых основывается эта уверенность. Или тот же опыт хотя бы: "Постоянно так делал, и никогда ничего не случалось".

Comment: Я по-своему понял замечание «рассматриваю как слабый». «Уверен, что не могла размагнититься», — так говорят и на основании опыта обращения с устройством..

Comment: Безусловно. А когда этого опыта нет, так уже сложно сказать, не слукавив.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании частиц двух частиц "ни" их можно опустить, и предложение при этом не сломается. И это по информации из справочников.

*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время не будет ни размагничиваться, ни как-то иначе портиться.*
Опускаем "ни":
*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время не будет размагничиваться, [или] как-то иначе портиться.*

Опускаем в вашем варианте:
*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время размагнитилась, как-то иначе испортилась?* || Всё наоборот.

Ответ Sharon корректным не является. Люди так не говорят. Но возможно, что когда-то говорили.

Предлагаю использовать усилительную частицу "и" вместо "ни":
*Я надеюсь, что карточка за это время и не размагнитилась, и никак иначе не испортилась.*
Частица "ни" перемещена в слово "никак". Эффект очень похож на тот, что задумывался.